# In how many ways the letters of word 'PERSON' can be arranged in the following way

Tags: combinatorics

Question: In how many ways the letters of word 'PERSON' can be arranged in the following way such that No row is empty and no letter is repeated

[image]

I was trying to solve this question, but my answer is getting wrong somewhere.
I know the actual solution, but it was a try to solve it in a different way below:

first select 3 words and arrange them in all rows so that we ensure no row is empty,

$\implies$ Total ways to do so is C($6$,$3$) $\cdot2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot3!$

Now select other words and arrange them without any restriction

$\implies$ Total ways = $5\cdot3\cdot4$

Therefore, Total no. of ways = $115,200$

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are overcounting.  You can't distinguish between the letters inserted initially to ensure that rows aren't empty and those that were inserted later on "without restriction".

Comment: Better to look at the possible patterns.  There are two blank squares in each pattern.  Where might they go?  Once the blank squares are placed, how many ways can you populate the rest of the squares?

Comment: Sorry but can you send your solution I cant understand this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complementary counting approach outlined by Darryl Johnson is optimal.

As lulu indicated in the comments, you overcounted.

To show you how, we first need to perform a direct count.  As lulu also indicated in the comments, we can obtain a direct count by choosing which two positions will be left empty, then populating the remaining six positions with the six distinct letters in the word PERSON.

There are four possibilities:

1. A position in row 1 and a position in row 2 are each left empty.
2. A position in row 1 and a position in row 3 are each left empty.
3. A position in row 2 and a position in row 3 are each left empty.
4. Two positions in row 3 are left empty.

*A position in row 1 and a position in row 2 are each left empty*:  There are $2$ ways to select the empty position in row 1 and $2$ ways to select the empty position in row 2.  There are $6!$ ways to arrange the letters of the word PERSON in the remaining six positions of the grid.  Hence, there are $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 6!$ such arrangements.

*A position in row 1 and a position in row 3 are each left empty*:   There are $2$ ways to select the empty position in row 1 and $4$ ways to select the empty position in row 3.  There are $6!$ ways to arrange the letters of the word PERSON in the remaining six positions of the grid.  Hence, there are $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6!$ such arrangements.

*A position in row 2 and a position in row 3 are each left empty*:  By symmetry, there are $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6!$ such arrangements.

*Two positions in row 3 are left empty*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two empty positions in row 3.  There are $6!$ ways to arrange the letters of the word PERSON in the remaining six positions of the grid.  Hence, there are $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 6!$ such arrangements.

*Total*:  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of admissible arrangements is
$$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 6! + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + \binom{4}{2}6! = 18,720$$
Notice that
$$P(8, 6) - 2 \cdot 6! = \frac{8!}{2!} - 2 \cdot 6! = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 6! + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + \binom{4}{2}6!$$

*Why is your attempt wrong?*

By designating a particular letter to be the letter that satisfies the requirement that a letter be in the $i$th row, you counted each arrangement as many times as a letter appears in the $i$th row.

*A position in row 1 and a position in row 2 are each left empty*:  Then there is one letter in the first row, one letter in the second row, and there are four letters in the third row.  You counted this case $4$ times, once for each of the ways you could have designated one of the four letters in the third row as the letter in the third row.

*A position in row 1 and a position in row 3 are each left empty*:  Then there is one letter in the first row, there are two letters in the second row, and there are three letters in the third row.  You counted this case $6$ times, once for each of the two ways you could have designated one of the two letters in the second row as the letter in the second row and once for each of the three ways you could have designated one of the three letters in the third row as the letter in the third row.

*A position in row 2 and a position in row 3 are each left empty*:  By symmetry, you also counted this case six times.

*Two positions in row 3 are left empty*:  This means there are $2$ letters in each of the three rows.  Therefore, you counted each arrangement in this case $8$ times, once for each of the two ways you could have designated one of the two letters in each row as the letter in that row.

Observe that
$$\color{red}{4} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 6! + \color{red}{6} \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + \color{red}{6} \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6! + \color{red}{8} \cdot \binom{4}{2}6! = \color{red}{115,200}$$

Answer (score 3):

Count the ways without restriction, subtract the ways that violate the restriction.

You can only violate it by leaving either row 1 or 2 empty.

Without restriction you have $P(8,6)$ arrangements.  There are $2 \cdot 6!$ arrangements that violate the restriction.

Comment: I know that approach but I want to know whats wrong with my solution

Comment: As the comments above have said, populating the columns first and then putting the remaining letters will lead to you double counting some arrangements.  For instnsce, first putting P in the first row first column, E in the second row first column, R in the third row first column and then filling in S in the first row second column (along ewith the others) yields, under your counting scheme, a different arrangement than choosing to put E in the first row second column in the intial row population.